There are some errors in the script I wrote. Can you help me? (About the geometry data panel)
Then I got help from @Harry McKenzie who helped me with the context issue, but after I re-modified the script, it didn't give an error, but bpy.ops.mesh.customdata_bevel_weight_edge_clear()
bpy.ops.mesh.customdata_bevel_weight_vertex_clear()
bpy.ops.mesh.customdata_crease_edge_clear()
bpy.ops.mesh.customdata_crease_vertex_clear() These operations are not executed. Can someone help me? Here is my script
import bpy

class ContextExecuterOverride:
    def __init__(self, window, screen, area, region):
        self.window, self.screen, self.area, self.region = window, screen, area, region
        self.legacy = not hasattr(bpy.context, "temp_override")
        if self.legacy:
            self.context = bpy.context.copy()
            self.context['window'] = window
            self.context['screen'] = screen
            self.context['area'] = area
            self.context['region'] = region
        else:
            self.context = bpy.context.temp_override(window=window, screen=screen, area=area, region=region)

    def __enter__(self):
        if not self.legacy:
            self.context.__enter__()
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        if not self.legacy:
            self.context.__exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback)
        return self

class ContextScriptExecuter():

    def __init__(self, area_type, ui_type=None, script=None):
        self.area_type = area_type
        self.ui_type = ui_type if ui_type else area_type
        self.script = script

    def script_content(self, override):
        self.script(override)

    def execute_script(self):
        window = bpy.context.window
        screen = window.screen
        areas = [area for area in screen.areas if area.type == self.area_type]
        area = areas[0] if len(areas) else screen.areas[0]
        prev_ui_type = area.ui_type
        area.ui_type = self.ui_type
        regions = [region for region in area.regions if region.type == 'WINDOW']
        region = regions[0] if len(regions) else None
        with ContextExecuterOverride(window=window, screen=screen, area=area, region=region) as override:
            self.script_content(override)
        area.ui_type = prev_ui_type


scene = bpy.context.scene

def clear_custom_data(obj):
    if obj.type == 'MESH':
        
        if obj.data.use_auto_smooth:
            obj.data.use_auto_smooth = False
        for edge in obj.data.edges:
            edge.bevel_weight = 0.0
        for vert in obj.data.vertices:
            vert.bevel_weight = 0.0

        
        for poly in obj.data.polygons:
            for loop_idx in poly.loop_indices:
                obj.data.loops[loop_idx].crease = 0.0


for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
    clear_custom_data(obj)


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add

Yes, it's the context

But there are still some problems, I updated the problem, such as the above

there is no such thing as bpy.ops.mesh.customdata_bevel_weight_edge_clear() where did you get that?

@Harry McKenzie '''bpy.ops.meshe.customdata_bevel_weight_edge_clear () '''  This is what I saw in the console when I clicked on the geometry data panel from the blender script page, and then the API documentation. https://docs.blender.org/api/3.6/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.customdata_bevel_weight_edge_clear

yeah but they only exist in Blender 3.6. In 4.0+ they are phased out

So you can't use this, can you? What should I do if I need to batch manipulate the geometry data panel?

unfortunately I don't know what the equivalent for these operators are in 4.0+. But why not just run it in 3.6 in the mean time? It should work there.

I guess the built-in python version of blender is not consistent. I'm looking for other information
